# deploying to websplehere app server @ localhost (WTE)

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7, rational-team-concert

I am trying to install my application into Websphere7 app server (WTE) in localhost.

The ear file is deployed through the console, but it seems I am able to test the application in the browser after starting the server.
There is an `index.jsp`, but when I try to access that I keep getting the `http 404 error` (there is no error on the path because the app is running on another server), I must be missing a config file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /utilities/pageerror.jsp
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3944)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it, the ear file was not built correctly

Comment: Good to know, more precise than my answer below. +1

Answer (score 0):

In a jazz.bet RTC context, you only have two threads mentioning this error:

- "[Error fetching item: Not Found - Error code 404 with JSP](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/53353/error-fetching-item-not-found-error-code-404-with-jsp)": recommending setting the following parameter on the Websphere Server:
  `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true`
- "[Need help to access View Test Plans & View Test Case opt](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/69984/need-help-to-access-view-test-plans-amp-view-test-case-opt)":

> I've already solved the problem just changing the browser default language to English instead of to leave it in Portuguese.

As the [OP mi3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1884445/mi3) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048796/6309), the root cause here was an invalid (incrrectly built) ear.

Comment: I am using English and it seems that the server doesn't recognize my ear file, but I got the ear from our QA server where it is running fine. I am thinking there must be a config param missing somewhere. Any thoughts... under what circumstannces websphere won't recognise a deployed ear installed through its own admin console....

Comment: @mi3 not sure, but why did you tag the question with RTC?